# What is the semantic difference between 'bizarre' and 'ridiculous'?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What is the semantic difference between words 'bizarre' and 'ridiculous'?

Comment: [**strange**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bizarre) vs [**laughable**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ridiculous). What is unclear about the dictionary definitions?

Comment: ***Bizarre*** has [risen in popularity](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bizarre%2Cridiculous&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbizarre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cridiculous%3B%2Cc0) to be on a par with ***ridiculous*** today.

Comment: ...but ***ridiculous murder*** is almost unknown [compared to ***bizarre murder***.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bizarre+murder%2Cridiculous+murder&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbizarre%20murder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cridiculous%20murder%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cbizarre%20murder%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cridiculous%20murder%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

Their dictionary definitions explain it pretty succinctly.
[Ridiculous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ridiculous):

> arousing or deserving ridicule : extremely silly or unreasonable : ABSURD, PREPOSTEROUS

[Bizarre](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bizarre):

> strikingly out of the ordinary: such as
>   
> a: odd, extravagant, or eccentric in style or mode His behavior was    bizarre. bizarre stories a bizarre outfit
>   
> b: involving sensational contrasts or incongruities

These words are not quite synonyms, but often can describe the same things. Something that is "odd, extravagant, or eccentric in style" can very commonly also be "deserving or arousing of ridicule".

In short you can think of bizarre as being more similar to "strange" or "weird", while ridiculous is more similar to "funny" or "silly".